# Corrupted RDP Certificate

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, certificate, corruption, bsod

One of our machines crashed earlier, so I connected to it to find out what the issue was. It has been spitting out the following error in the logs for the past couple of days apparently...

> The RDP protocol component X.224 detected an error in the protocol
>   stream and has disconnected the client.

Prior to that (about a week ago) it looks like it was getting this instead...

> The RDP protocol component "DATA ENCRYPTION" detected an error in the
>   protocol stream and has disconnected the client.

From what I read [HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2477176) it sounds like a Corrupted Certificate. I read the steps to fix it, but this is a machine we rent from a Datacenter, so the only access I have is RDP. If I am going to have to do delete the registry key and reactivate the "Remote Desktop Services Licensing server", I am assuming this can't be done remotely?